# Добавлять класс и атрибуты в зависимости от размера экрана на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Здорова, друзья!

Есть **sidebar** , и хотелось бы, чтобы при размере **< 992px**  к этому sidebar добавлялись :

```
   class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasWithBackdrop"             
   aria-labelledby="offcanvasWithBackdropLabel"
```

Просто внутри данного меню есть элемент , на котором применяется функция,

И мне очень интересно, если удастся провернуть такую махинацию с добавлением вышеуказанных классов и атрибутов , функция не прервется?

Comment: Здорова. Вот [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/509258/) , полистай.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Спасибо, спасаете!